# Add t() function in tpl.php page

Tags: i18n-l10n

Hi I have this line in a tpl.php file. I would like to add t () function to be able to translate it. What needs to be changed in this line?

```
print "<div class='confirm-app'><h2><span class='voice-header'>1. Your application</span></h2>".$application."</div>";
```

Comment: It depends - what do you want to translate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print "<div class='confirm-app'><h2><span class='voice-header'>1. " . t('Your application') . "</span></h2>".$application."</div>";
```